# How to access the formatted text within an Excel cell with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have embedded formatting within an excel column.  For example, a cell might contain some (but not all) italicised words.

The `.Value`, `.Value2` and `.Text` properties seem to strip any formattting.
I want to be able to "see" the formatting with VBA so I can act upon it.

Is there a property to allow me to access this information?

Answer (score 1):

Did some more research and it looks like the `.Characters` property is the way to do it.